# Find Acumatica's version on code

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to pass as a parameter for the report AR641500 the Customer ID, but this parameters field name is different for Acumatica's version 2018R1 ("StatementCustomerId") and 2017R2 ("CustomerID") on the Report Designer.
`

```
reportID = myDet.ActivityReport;
parms = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parms["StatementCustomerId"] = bAccountRow.AcctCD.Trim();

newFileName = String.Format("{0} {1}.PDF", reportID, bAccountRow.AcctCD);

data = CWReportGenerator.GetAcuReportBytes(reportID, parms);`
```

[Acumatica 2017R2 "CustomerID" parameter name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFxKu.png)

[Acumatica 2018R2 "StatementCustomerId" parameter name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm3hd.png)

I want to be able to handle both scenarios on code, is there anyway to know Acumatica's current version on runtime? I reviewed the AccessInfo DAC, but it doesn't have that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on `PX.Data.PXVersionInfo.Version`.